# Argument of type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'

Tags: graphql, vuejs3, quasar

I'm using Vue3 Quasar with GraphQL.

I'm getting the following warning in Visual Studio Code:

***Argument of type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'***

The warning is happening on the line of code that I've marked below.

This code runs, but the warning makes it so that the color coding is not working in VS Code.
Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

I've googled it and tried the obvious ways.  The thing is that I'm assigning it here to a constant number, so it can't be null.  I don't understand why it thinks it can be null.

```
const { refetch: oneUserFetch, loading: oneUserLoading } = useQuery(gql`
query oneUser($id: Int!) {
    oneUser(userId: $id) {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
`);


async function onClickSubmit() {
  //I'm getting a warning on this next line: Argument of type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'
  const fetchedUser = await oneUserFetch({ id: 344});  
}
```

Comment: You're calling `refetch` with arguments. `refetch` doesn't take arguments, it refetches with the initial arguments. That's why it's called `refetch` and not `fetchMore`.

Comment: oh okay, that makes sense.  The weird thing is that it is working though.  But it's giving that warning.  Do you know the correct way to do this?  I want to be able to send it a new userId in the button event (every time the button is clicked).